# Spark master node ip not updated in Zookeeper store after failover

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

We were working on spark HA setup in multi node cluster. What we have seen that after stand by spark machine becomes "Alive" the zookeeper data store for master is not updated , it still has the old machine ip address , we thought of building an application which will use this info and return back with current master in typical HA setup , but because of this bug in Zookeeper , we are not able to build that application. like zookeeper has the data :-

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] get /sparkha/master_status
10.49.1.112
cZxid = 0x10000007f
ctime = Wed Sep 14 23:52:52 PDT 2016
mZxid = 0x10000007f
mtime = Wed Sep 14 23:52:52 PDT 2016
pZxid = 0x10000007f
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 11
numChildren = 0
```

after failover the ip should be changed to new machine ip. we wanted to know is it a bug or we are missing something ?
We know about spark-damon.sh status but we were more focusing on ZK store.
Thanks

Comment: Have you passed both masters to the running job? We need a little more information.

Comment: Thanks Yuval , we are passing both masters , and spark would take care of forwarding the task to live one . This is as per the spark documentation also. But we were thinking of to get rid of this slight performance from round robin check of master list and provide directly the current master by building some app on ZK .